# Python 3D linear interpolation without knowing the functional form

Tags: python, interpolation

I need to interpolate data in 3 dimensions. So I have a data file which has 4 columns x,y,z and D. D is basically a function of x,y and z but I don't know the exact functional form. Only thing I have is some discrete values of x,y,z and corresponding value of D. I need to interpolate D at all points so that I have a function D_interp=f(x,y,z) so that I can just give any values of x,y and z and the function will return the value of D at those co-ordinates. Any idea how can we do that?

Comment: This is more likely *regression* than *interpolation*. Have a look at the `scikit-learn` package for some linear regressors. Unless you have available neighboring values for all the missing data, in which case you can use `scipy`'s interpolation functions.

Comment: Yes the values are at small intervals. So I have all the neighbouring values. I think it will be possible to do the interpolation. I tried griddata and LinearNDinterpolator of scipy. But I don't know how to do it if I don't have the functional form.

Comment: So.. to clarify the problem a bit, `x,y,z` are grid points and you have all them available within a range? The problem varies a lot depending of how your existing data is arranged.. if its just a series of `x,y,z -> D` values it can be seen as *regression*. If you have data points in a grid, and you want to interpolate subgrid values then it is an *interpolation* problem. If what you have is grid data, but you have some values missing, you can either do interpolation with neighbors or use something like *image inpainting*. You can always try interpolating with K-NN.

Comment: So I have the data points like this 
x=['4.0', '4.050000190734863', '4.099999904632568', '4.150000095367432',...............]
y=['1.0','1.01',1.03'..........]
z=[-05,-10,-15.......]
and D=['-25.649999618530273', '-24.270000457763672', '-23.280000686645508', '-22.469999313354492',....]

Comment: OK, so those are NOT *discrete* values of XYZ. Discrete stands for integer values. What you have are some samples of continuous data. Try doing either [regression with scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html) or some kind of [Nearest Neighbors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_regression.html#example-neighbors-plot-regression-py):

By splitting your data in 2 matrices:

```
X = [n_samples x 3] 
y = [n_samples]
```

where `X` contains XYZ **available** coordinates and `y` contains the **available** `D` data, you can use it to interpolate the rest of values (name them `X_test`) as follows:

```
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors)
y_test = knn.fit(X, y).predict(X_test)
```

and `y_test` will have the missing values of `D`.

Comment: Sorry I am new to python. So the X is a 3 dimensional array which is basically X=[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2].......]or is it like X=[[x1,x2,x3....],[y1,y2,y3...],[z1,z2,z3....]]??

Comment: The first option, `X = [[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2]...]` and `y = [D1, D2, ...]`. I would suggest you to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays. If you are new to python, I would suggest you to have a look to the [scipy tutorial](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/), as it contains an overview of how to operate with python's scientific (numeric) stack (numpy, scipy, maptlotlib...).

Comment: @ArpanDas forgot to mention you in the above comment :/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But can you tell me again what is X_test?  @imaluengo

Comment: @ArpanDas `X_test` = the data points for which you don't have the `D` value. In other words, the XYZ coordinates where you want to interpolate.

Comment: @ArpanDas if you found the answer useful, please consider up-voting or accepting it (in case it solved your problem).